# Admin and user login using one login button in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have two modules login and admin and have one login button.I want admin and user should login through one login button but their pages should appear then according to their username and password they have entered.

```
private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter dt = new OleDbDataAdapter("select uid from [admin] where uname='"+txtuname.Text+"' and pass='"+txtpass.Text+"' ",con);
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            dt.Fill(t);
            if (t.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                main m = new main();
                this.Visible = false;
                m.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("wrong userid or password");
            }
            con.Close();
         
        }
```

I want to add that code in this section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to create one table you can give name **Users**

Now in this table you have to set role ,

role can be admin and user

Now when anyone enter login information then you have to check password and username and get information of that user

If user is admin then redirect to admin template if user then redirect to user

For example

```
if(role=="admin"){
//redirect to admin
}
if(role=="user"){
//redirect to user
}
```

Comment: But i already have created table for user and admin in access. And role can be done in sql.

Comment: You have to add role , If you want to use one login for both, Because without role your not able to identified which user information is added and where to you redirect it